# How to access a Material Editor node from a script?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal, materials, blueprints

Is it possible to access a node from the Material Editor from a C++ script?

I'd like to be able to change the value of 'Mulitply' from a script.

[image]

Comment: It sounds to me like you might want to make a [Material Parameter](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/RenderingAndGraphics/Materials/HowTo/Making_Parameters/) out of your multiplication coefficient.

Comment: Thank you! I will look right into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Material, create a Scalar Parameter (hold 1 on the material grid and left click), name it and plug it in to your multiply node.

In your C++ header, create an instance variable and set it as a UPROPERTY so it doesn't get garbage collected.

```
UPROPERTY()
UMaterialInstanceDynamic* DynMat;
```

In your C++ constructor, set the dynamic material instance from the existing material on your mesh then set it to your mesh.

```
DynMat = UMaterialInstanceDynamic::Create(YOURMESHNAME->GetMaterial(0), this);
YOURMESHNAME->SetMaterial(0, DynMat)
```

The 0 in the get and set refer to which Element of the mesh the material is set to.  If 0 is the back of the card and 1 is the front, change the code accordingly.

From here, you can use the DynMat reference to change your parameter values as follows.

```
MI->SetScalarParameterValue(TEXT("YourMultiplierName"), NewFloatValue);
```

YourMultiplierName must match exactly what you put in for the name of the parameter in the material grid, otherwise this won't work.

Comment: thanks mate. I did already get it working due to DMGregory's help, but nice to have it all typed up with example. I would upvote but I don't have enough rep